# Trigger Automator folder action when content of a folder is removed

Tags: automator, folder-action

I want to trigger the automator folder action when I remove a file from a folder, is there a way to achieve this?
The folder action works perfectly when I add something to it but not when I remove it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**

It is perhaps better if I give more details about what I want to achieve.
I have a folder on the desktop and I want his color to change depending on whether it is full or empty. I have already a working shell code which works perfectly when I run it through terminal.

Using that shell code with automator folder action works only when I put a new file inside the folder but not when I remove it.

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's possible. Can you explain your workflow a bit more? Perhaps there's another way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Script Editor.app**, paste this following **AppleScript** code into a new document, then name and save it as a “scpt” file to /Users/**YOUR_SHORT_NAME**/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions folder.

I don't know what your "working shell code" is so I used code for changing the folder labels in Finder as an example

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    --
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    tell application "Finder" to set label index of theFolder to 3
end adding folder items to

on removing folder items from theFolder after losing removedItemNames
    --  Called after items have been removed from a folder
    --
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  removedItemNames is a list of names of items removed from the folder
    tell application "Finder"
        set theCount to count of items of entire contents of theFolder
        if theCount = 0 then
            set label index of theFolder to 0
        end if
    end tell
end removing folder items from
```

After this code is tweaked to your liking, and has been saved to the previous mentioned folder, it will then be available to use within the **Folder Actions Setup.app** to to attach to any folder of your choice.

---

***FYI***: These are all of your **Folder Action** options you can use with your **AppleScripts**

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theNewItems
    --  Called after items have been added to a folder
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  theNewItems is a list of references to the items added to the folder 
    -- your code goes here
end adding folder items to

on removing folder items from theFolder after losing removedItemNames
    --  Called after items have been removed from a folder
    --  theFolder is a reference to the modified folder
    --  removedItemNames is a list of names of items removed from the folder
    -- your code goes here
end removing folder items from

on closing folder window for theFolder
    --  Called when a folder's window is closed in the Finder
    --  theFolder is a reference to the closed folder
    -- your code goes here
end closing folder window for

on moving folder window for theFolder from previousBounds
    --  Called when a folder's Finder window has been moved or resized
    --  theFolder is a reference to the folder being altered
    --  previousBounds is old position and size of the folder's Finder window
    -- your code goes here
end moving folder window for
```

Comment: Many thanks! That is exactly what I wanted to achieve! Have a nice day :)